# Show set is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that the set

$A=\{n^2+m^2:n,m\in \mathbb{N}\}$

is countable.

Is it enough to state that, since $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under multiplication and addition, the set A must be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$; and since any subset of a countable set is countable, A must be countable?

Comment: Yes, it is; in fact that’s probably the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Unless you define "countable" as "infinite and countable", in which case you need to prove that $A$ is infinite (which shoud be almost trivial).